# Is there an Eclipse equivalent to VS Studio "Go to All" (CTRL + T)

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio

What is Eclipse's closest equivalent to https://executecommands.com/visual-studio-2019-code-navigation/

Comment: _Open Resource_ (Ctrl+Shift+R)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by howlger, the closest is **Ctrl*+Shift+R**. Additionally, these shortcuts are useful as well:

- **Ctrl+3**: Search everywhere, including files and IDE commands.
- **Ctrl+Shift+T**: Open type.
- **Ctrl+O**: Quick outline in current file (class members).
- **Ctrl+Shift+L**: Shows a ***L***ist of shortcuts.

* In Mac, replace Ctrl with Cmd.